# Do any members of the Legion of Super-Pets have Kryptonian capes?

Tags: dc, superman, costume

In some versions of *Superman*, Superman actually has many capes. Those made with Earth-based materials are destructible, and are the ones we usually see torn and bullet-ridden. However, his original Kryptonian blanket, usually mentioned as being made from the blanket that he was wrapped in when he came to Earth, is indestructible as he is.

Has there ever been mention of whether or not Krypto or [any of the other Super animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Super-Pets) have their own authentic Kryptonian Super Cape™?

Or, on the flip-side, is there evidence showing that their capes are indeed destructible, such as images with them being ripped or tattered?

---

Comics preferred, but animated specials acceptable. Krypto, for instance, has a 60 year history, and any of it is fine.

Comment: Could you edit the title to make clear that you're interested in other Super animals and not just Krypto, as you say in the question body?

Comment: @randal'thor I'm most interested in Krypto specifically, but I'll work something out.

Answer (score 3):

**Comet, the super-horse, is promised a super-cape:**

> Supergirl has several dreams about Comet, a white super-horse who performs amazing feats. Later, she and her parents go to a "Supergirl Dude Ranch", where they meet with the real Comet, a white horse whom only she (as Linda Danvers) can claim. Comet demonstrates that he really has super-powers and, by taking her to the giant image of Supergirl outside the ranch, indicates to Linda that he knows her secret identity. **She promises to make him a red super-cape to wear** later on, and wonders where Comet came from.

(from "The Super-Steed of Steel!", [Action Comics #292](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_292)).

---

**Streaky, the super-cat, also gets a super-cape:**

> "Hearing a ear-spittling yowling" brings Superman in. Superman 
>   decides to split up the two-Superman bet. Supergirl reveals that 
>   Streaky is "jealous because he saw me petting Krypto!  I only did so 
>   because he had done a good deed fore me!" Superman decides to a "tug-
>   of-war"--but before Streaky and Krypto got at it--**Supergirl gives 
>   Streaky a super-cape**--and Krypto is cheered up by Superman.

(from "The Battle of the Super-Pets", [Action Comics #277](http://silveragereviews.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/supergirl-archives-vol-2-part-2.html)).

Comment: In this case, it's not clear to me if Super-cape is referring to an indestructible cape, or just a cape following the iconic design. The term "super-cape" is a bit generic, and in my experience generally refers to the style (red, flowing, usually S shield), rather than the material.

Comment: This is the first I have heard of Comet, the Super-Horse. Thank you for starting my day off on the wrong hoof- err...foot.